# Grammar usage of "と、～た"

Tags: grammar, particle-と

I'm not completely sure on the grammar usage of と、～た, in these following sentences, but have been given the general explanation that the imply an unexpected result following a normal (one time?) action.

１．弟は昼ごはんを食べると、片付けもせずに出かけてしまった。

２．私が「ごめん」と言うと、友達は「あやまるのはぼくのほうだ」と言った。

I'm also unsure of how to translate と as it applies to the first half of the sentence in these cases either, or the tense.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/46693/what-did-they-mean-to-use-%e3%81%8f%e3%82%8b-in-the-past-time

Answer (score 2):

「と」は接続助詞といいます。
It is a connective particle.

> １．弟は昼ごはんを食べると、片付けもせずに出かけてしまった。
>   ２．私が「ごめん」と言うと、友達は「あやまるのはぼくのほうだ」と言った。

In these phrases, the connective particle "shows at the opportunity when a certain situation happens or an opportunity to notice it."

- When my younger brother finished eating lunch, he has gone out without clearing the table.
- When I said "I'm sorry," my friend said "It's me that should apologize to you."