# Understanding Omitted Elements in the Body of a Newspaper Article

Tags: reading-comprehension

I have trouble interpreting the following sentence from [an article about the yen exchange rate](http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20170814/k10011099101000.html).

> 連休明けの１４日の東京外国為替市場は、北朝鮮情勢に対する警戒感からリスクを避けようと、比較的、安全な通貨とされる円を買ってドルを売る動きが出て、円相場は、ドルに対して値上がりしています。

I am aware that "obvious" particles, する (and its continuative form し), repeated subjects, etc., could be omitted in the body of newspaper articles. The following is my attempted interpretation of the above sentence.

> 連休明けの１４日の東京外国為替市場は、北朝鮮 **（の）** 情勢に対する警戒感からリスクを避けようと **（し）**、  比較的、安全な通貨とされる円を買ってドルを売る動きが出て、円相場は、ドルに対して値上がりしています。
>
> (After a long holiday, the Tokyo Foreign Exchange Market on the 14th attempted to avoid risks from senses of caution regarding North Korean state of affairs, and a trend started where yen, which was considered as a relatively safe currency, was bought and US dollars were sold, and the yen exchange rate against the US dollar increased.)

I decided on 「避けようと（し）」 because I know {volitional form}+とする could be used to describe someone attempting an action. **Was there really an omitted し, or is there some function of the と particle (such as [the one used for describing successive events](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/46754/grammar-usage-of-%E3%81%A8-%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%9F)) that I am not noticing?**

Note: The duplicate question suggested by @naruto appears to be related, but if we consider the clause with と as an adverbial clause, then the sentence appears ungrammatical, because the topic appears as the agent of the **intransitive** verb 出る and the subject acts as some direct object. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of と in 友蔵が出おくれまいと言いそえた](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/42287/meaning-of-%e3%81%a8-in-%e5%8f%8b%e8%94%b5%e3%81%8c%e5%87%ba%e3%81%8a%e3%81%8f%e3%82%8c%e3%81%be%e3%81%84%e3%81%a8%e8%a8%80%e3%81%84%e3%81%9d%e3%81%88%e3%81%9f)

Comment: @naruto Are you suggesting that there is actually an implied (but understood) verb of thinking, saying, or etc., after と?

Comment: @binon That's one way of understanding this, but ～ようと and ～まいと are so common that I don't know if it's right to say we need to think about an implied verb.

Comment: @naruto According to A Dictionary of Intermediate Japanese Grammar, this usage of と "makes an adverbial clause, with a verb of saying/thinking understood after it" (p. 464) and claims the grammatical pattern as {volitional form}と（思って / して）, which is quite similar to the answers of the question you redirected me. But, setting this aside, the note I added onto my question is why I had further confusion and decided on  「避けようと（し）」

Comment: I have been many times heard and seen that learners claim that they find it difficult to grasp this usage of と and they tend to add another verb to complement, otherwise it looks ungrammatical. That's probably why that book teaches that way. However, native speakers won't grasp it that way. To me, adding し would rather make the sentence disproportional because the と clause would then be parallel to 動きが出て despite it's actually modifying it. In other words, it could be rearranged into 避けようという動きが出て.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 連休明けの１４日の東京外国為替市場は、北朝鮮情勢に対する警戒感からリスクを避けようと、比較的、安全な通貨とされる円を買ってドルを売る動きが出て、円相場は、ドルに対して値上がりしています。

大変長い文ですが、次のように変更して理解するとわかりやすいと思います。

> 連休明けの１４日の東京外国為替市場は、<del>北朝鮮**の**情勢に対する警戒感**が理由で、**</del>（ドルが値下がりするであろう）リスクを避けようと**して**、比較的、安全な通貨とされる円を買ってドルを売る動きが出て**いる。** **そのために**、円相場は、ドルに対して値上がりしています。

あるいは、

> #### EDIT
>
> 連休明けの１４日の東京外国為替市場は、北朝鮮**の**情勢に対する警戒感から（**生じるであろう**）（**ドル値下がりの**）リスクを避けようと**して**、比較的、安全な通貨とされる円を買ってドルを売る動きが出て**いる。** **そのために**、円相場は、ドルに対して値上がりしています。

変更点とその理由は次のようになっています。

- 理解を深めるために、太字の部分を補充しました。
- 「北朝鮮の情勢に対する警戒感からリスクを避ける」と解釈すると間違いなので、一旦「北朝鮮**の**情勢に対する警戒感から」を削除して解釈してください。
- 「リスクを避ける」の前に「ドルが値下がりするであろう」のような意味が省略されています。従って「リスク」は「ドルの値下がりリスク」です。当然、「リスクを避ける」は「ドルの値下がりリスクを避ける」です。
- 「北朝鮮**の**情勢に対する警戒感から」は「北朝鮮**の**情勢に対する警戒感**が理由で、**」のような意味です。「北朝鮮**の**情勢に対する警戒感から」の「から」を生かすなら、「北朝鮮の警戒感から**生じるであろう** (ドル値下がりの)リスクを ...」と解釈しても良いと思います。
- 「安全な通貨とされる円を買ってドルを売る動きが出て、」は一度文を終わらす方が理解しやすい。従って、「～ドルを売る動きが出ている。 そのために、円相場は、～」としました。

Comment: 「because of ~」を縮めるために「from ~」と書きましたが、それでもまだ間違っていると思います。ところで、編集した文は元の文より読みやすいね。

Comment: binom:>「because of ~」を縮めるために「from ~」と書きましたが、それでもまだ間違っていると思います。このコメントがどこを指すかわかりませんが、もし、「... 警戒感からリスクを ...」の箇所｛かしょ｝であれば、「... 警戒感から **生じるであろう** ドル値下がりのリスクを ...」と解釈してはどうですか。

Comment: 「because of ~」の代わりに「from ~」を書いたので、私の「北朝鮮情勢に対する警戒感から」の翻訳が間違っていると思っていた。